# What were the Slytherins doing during the battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-2

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows : Part 2* which is the movie version of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, the Slytherins were sent to dungeons by Professor McGonagall. I know in the books they were just evacuated. But as you can see in the video above, the Slytherin students were able to escape the dungeons. Now, the question is where did they go afterwards? And whose side were they fighting for?

Comment: This is answered over at SF&F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/which-side-did-the-slytherins-ultimately-fight-for-at-the-battle-of-hogwarts

Comment: @Paulie_D Doesn't seem to adress the movie, does it? Apparently in the books they were evacuated.

Comment: Since it's apparently not **in** the movie...what else can we rely on?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Also this is dupe post by the same OP over on SF&F...I understand that's a no-no? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159862/where-did-the-slytherin-house-go-during-the-battle-of-hogwarts

Comment: @Paulie_D Ah, I see. Still a difficult situation since he claims the answer is supposed to be different for the movies and there the question was just closed as a duplicate of a pure book-answer (in fact the question there didn't care much about the specific version, while this one does).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson This is just a long line of comments and questions by this OP. He just doesn't seem satisfied with the canon answers he's getting - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162694/who-was-phineas-nigellus-black-talking-about If there is nothing in the movie (and from recollection there isn't) I don't see how this can be reconciled to the OPs satisfaction.

Comment: Put in mind that the question at scifi stack exchange is another site. And that site is only referring to the books.This one is in the movies.

Answer (score 1):

Thank [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-many-Slytherin-students-fought-at-the-Battle-of-Hogwarts-on-either-side) for this answer:

Let’s tally up the Slytherins whose whereabouts we know…

When it became clear that the Slytherins were quite willing to deliver Harry to Voldemort, Pansy Parkinson and the bulk of them were escorted out of the Great Hall first, to be brought to the Room of Requirement and then through the Hog’s Head, where the students were expected to escape from the upcoming battle. If we go by Voldemort’s words:

> “He (Draco) did not come and join me, like the rest of the Slytherins”

We can assume that, instead of going home, they instead joined Voldemort’s forces. Likely most if not all of their parents were either Death Eaters or Voldemort followers.

Crabbe, Goyle and Malfoy had doubled back a lot earlier than that, and decided to lay in ambush, under a Disillusionment Charm, by the door of the Requirement Room, hoping to capture Harry so they could deliver him to Voldemort. They may not have been fighting by his side, but they were still fighting ON his side.

So it would appear that each and every Slytherin student fought for Voldemort bar none, and the only Slytherins who fought against Voldemort were the teachers - Slughorn, openly, and Snape, covertly.

Comment: But are there slytherin students who fought against Voldemort in the movie?

Comment: Yes, those very few that proved themselves to Hogwarts that they didn't belong in SLytherin, I can't remember names, but I know there was a few, the rest went with the death eaters and Voldemort

Comment: W8,your comment was "they didn't belong in slytherin " ?What do you mean

Comment: Another words, they didn't want to be in Slytherin. Like Harry wished for the sortting hat to  not put him in Slytherin. Some students just got unlucky.

Comment: But slytherin house itself is not bad.

Comment: natural,So to sum up there were slytherins students who fought against Voldemort?

Comment: Yes, in fact there was.

Comment: Do you have evidence.

Comment: @The Witch King of Angmar Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier, I have been busy. The evidence is in the movie if you watch it yourself.

Comment: Is there a YouTube clip, about it? If so what time of the video

Comment: Hold on, I will improve my post.

Comment: W8, so the slytherin teachers are the only ones who are against voldemort.  What about the slytherin students.

Comment: There are no "Slytherin teachers" merely teachers who were in Slytherin as students.

Comment: Teachers in houses were in fact called 'head of house', McGonagall being Gryffindor, Snape being Slytherin and other two I can't remember, but there are certain teachers that are in the house (as McGonagall says in the philosophers stone '*yes Mr Weasley, even from my own house*'), that is when she took points from both Harry and Ron after yet doing something else. The rest of the teachers are there purely there to teach and have no involvement within the houses. They give/deduct points yes, but they themselves are not in them, just four teachers for the four houses as '*head of house*'.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11478/70135 
It says here that the Slytherins fought back.